# How can I remove/hide all toolbars from a QMainWindow?

Tags: qt4, qmainwindow

I have a third party QMainWindow and I need to embed it in my own QMainWindow (i.e. use it as a normal widget). I know it's not a best practise (to say the least) but I have no other way right now.

I need to hide the third-party window's statusbar, menubar and toolbars.
I was able to remove the statusbar (setStatusBar(0)) and the menubar (setMenuBar(0)) but I cannot find a way to do the samething with the toolbar area

Is there any way to hide/remove toolbars?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you get the pointer of the [StatusBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html#statusBar),[MenuBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html#menuBar), and call hide() on them.

As for the toolbars, you should find them:

```
QList<QToolBar *> toolbars = mainWindow.findChildren<QToolBar *>();
```

Then call hide() for them.

Comment: Thanks. But why statusBar()->hide() is better than setStatusBar(0)?